# how to solve errors in sklearn library for gmm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I imported pickle

```
import _pickle as cPickle
```

and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    models    = [cPickle.load(open(fname,'rb')) for fname in gmm_files]
    models    = [cPickle.load(open(fname,'rb')) for fname in gmm_files]
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.mixture.gmm'
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a wrong scikit learn version. The module sklearn.mixture.gmm is deprecated since version 0.18 and was removed in v0.20. So you have some Options:

1. Downgrade your scikit learn
   Example:

   pip uninstall scikit-learn

   pip install scikit-learn==0.19.2
2. Change your code so that it it tries to import `from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture`